# Why is change proxy settings disabled in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

I'm using windows 10 64 bit and Google Chrome Version 44.0.2403.125 m (64-bit).

I want to change the proxy settings but it's disabled in Google Chrome's settings.

I know that it is possible to change proxy settings from internet options -> connections -> LAN settings in Internet Explorer and Control Panel, but what is the problem for Google Chrome? How can I enable it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the advanced settings? Or Googled the problem? It should be there as there are a bunch of people who seem to be able to change the proxy settings in Windows 10 on Chrome. Also, Google might have moved it when modifying it for Windows 10 so maybe try Googling where to find it? Otherwise I'd recommend just using your internet settings.

Comment: Yes. i Have checked the advanced settings and googled that.I just want to know why the change proxy settings is disable now? however it was enable before.

Comment: From what I'm seeing, this is only a problem for you apparently. I'm guessing a bug maybe? It seems other people CAN in fact change the proxy settings on Chrome in Windows 10. (If I'm wrong please link me where you found the evidence).

So your answer is: a bug I'm guessing with your chrome. 

I'd recommend re-installing it, switching browsers, or deleting chrome COMPLETELY (look up tutorials) then installing it again because when uninstalling programs, they usually leave files behind so when you install them again, you get the same bugs. :) hope this helped.